# Erase rects in Canvas, but they come back

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to write a small Tetris clone to learn Canvas. I've got as far as having a single block fall. I'm simply having it fall down one column in a 'for' loop, redrawing in the grid square below and then erasing the square above using rectClear. (The clumsy alert() is to see progress).

```
for (var y = 21; y >= 0; y--) {
    drawSquare(3,y,'green');
    clearSquare(3,(y+1));
    alert(y);
};
```

Interestingly, if I swap the "clearSquare" and "drawSquare" lines, none get erased at all.

I'm not sure if this is a problem in my logic, or if I'm failing to grasp something in canvas. As you can see I've clumsily put in "context.save()" in case my changes weren't being "committed" or something, but I believe this is kind of irrelevant here.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qys574b9/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `rect()` will add a rectangle to the current path every time it is called. Clearing the canvas will only clear the pixels, not the path, so next time you fill/stroke it will be included, hence reappear.

To solve simply call this tp the `drawSquare` method before adding a rectangle:

```
ctx.beginPath();   // this will start a new path, clearing the old
ctx.rect(...);
```

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/qys574b9/2/)**

Comment: Well that worked perfectly thanks but I'm still not sure why! Does it keep adding more and more squares to the current path, which all get drawn when you call .stroke() and .fill()?

Comment: @Jess yes, the path object is separate from the canvas bitmap so every time a shape is added to it you have to clear it to get rid of those, independent of what is rasterized to the screen/canvas. You can alternatively use fillRect() and strokeRect() which does not add to the path.